# Formatting Output in textfile using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to return output for below in rows and cols style not one after another.

```
$path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\Installed Hotfixes Info.txt";
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName . | fl * | Format-Table -AutoSize |fl > $path; notepad $path;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Format-List` (`fl`):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName . |
    Format-Table -AutoSize |
    Out-File $path
```

Better yet, export the output as CSV:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName . |
    Export-Csv $path -NoType
```

Comment: isn't it possible to get output in rowsXcols rather then using csv, wen u run this powershell it gets perfect formatting however in textfile everything comes one after another